# jQuery - remove accordion from HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a SharePoint 2013 environment.  Somebody prior to my starting at this business created HTML and CSS scripts to create an accordion effect with three pictures side-by-side, with links, that expand when hovered over.

The team has now asked that I remove the accordion affect and just have the images statically side by side. Having no real experience with jQuery, I'm at a bit of a loss.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://intranet/sites/hr/js/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#accordion > li').hover(
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.stop().animate({'width':'400px'},400);
            $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
            $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(400);
            $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.stop().animate({'width':'125px'},1000);
            $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
            $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
            $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(600);
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

```css
ul.accordion{
    list-style:none;   
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
ul.accordion li{
    float:right;
    width:120px;
    height:400px;
    display:block;
    border-right:2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
}
ul.accordion li.bg1{
    background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
}
ul.accordion li.bg2{
    background-image:url("../images/People400.jpg");
}
ul.accordion li.bg3{
    background-image:url("../images/Performance400.jpg");
}
ul.accordion li.bg4{
    background-image:url("../images/Potential400.jpg");
}
ul.accordion li.bleft{
    border-left:2px solid #fff;
}
ul.accordion li .heading{
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:60px;
    opacity:1;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#1F497D;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
}
ul.accordion li .description{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    display:none;
}
ul.accordion li .description h2{
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-size:45px;
    color:#1F497D;
    text-align:left;
    margin:2px 0px 15px 20px;
    text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
}
ul.accordion li .description p{
    line-height:14px;
    margin:10px 22px;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #1F497D;
}
ul.accordion li .description a{
    padding: 5px;
    bottom:5px;
    left:20px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-size:12px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#F79646;
}
ul.accordion li .description a:hover{
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

ul.accordion li .bgDescription{
    background:transparent url(../images/bgDescription.png) repeat-x top left;
    height:300px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">
    <head>
        <title>HR - People. Performance. Potential.</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Human Resource site" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Human Resource,"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
        <style>
            *{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
            }
            body{
                font-family:Arial;
                background:#fff repeat top left;
            }
            a{
                color:#444;
            }
            a:hover{
                color:#999; 
            }
            .title{
                width:700px;
                height:400px;
                position:absolute;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
            }
            a.back{
                background:transparent url(back.png) no-repeat top left;
                position:fixed;
                width:150px;
                height:27px;
                outline:none;
                bottom:0px;
                left:0px;
            }
            #content{
                margin:0 auto;
            }
            .reference{
                clear:both;
                top:300px;
                left:0px;
                position:absolute;
                text-align:right;
                width:400px;
                padding:20px;
                background-color:#fff;
                -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #ddd;
                -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #ddd;
                box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #ddd;
            }
            .reference p a{
                text-transform:uppercase;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
                color:#666;
                text-decoration:none;
                font-size:10px;
            }
            .reference p a:hover{
                color:#333;
            }

        </style>
    
 
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">F5RN5Q3VV7Q3-34-60</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">14938db6-45be-4314-bef6-093a88df00d7</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://intranet/sites/hr/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=F5RN5Q3VV7Q3-34-60, F5RN5Q3VV7Q3-34-60</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml><![endif]-->
</head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="title"></div>
            
            <ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
                <li class="bg4">
                    <div class="heading">Potential</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Potential</h2>
                        <p>
       <a href="http://intranet/sites/hr/Pages/Development.aspx" target="_blank">Development</a><br/>
      </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                
                <li class="bg3">
                    <div class="heading">Performance</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>Performance</h2>
                        <p>
       <a href="http://intranet/sites/hr/Pages/Framework.aspx" target="_blank">Framework</a><br/>
      </p>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li class="bg2" id="People">
                    <div class="heading">People</div>
                    <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                    <div class="description">
                        <h2>People</h2>
       <p>
        <a href="http://intranet/sites/hr/Pages/Service.aspx" target="_blank">Service</a><br/>
       </p>
      
                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to know how I remove the accordion function and just have them sitting statically side by side? Happy to provide the additional HTML and CSS if you require.

Comment: when you create *Code snippet* you should include complete code, i.e. in your case the html and maybe the css too

Comment: You need to include all the html from <ul id="accordion"> as well as all of the css used for it. Your solution will most likely involve having to delete the javascript code (dont delete the jquery library if jquery is being used elsewhere) and update your css so that the width/opacity/visiblity is as it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remove it by commenting out, or deleting the function.

```
   $(function() {
       /*
            $('#accordion > li').hover(
            function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'400px'},400);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(400);
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'165px'},1000);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(600);
                }
            );
       */
   });
```

Everything between the /* */ is commented out and won't work anymore. Probably best to comment it out, in case they change their minds.

Also, in your html, you will probably find 'display:none' on your link containers.  If you want the links to be visible, remove that.

If more visual corrections are needed, you would need to post css.

Try the Fiddle for playing with your css edits:
https://jsfiddle.net/gjs6La6d/

Comment: Your suggestion does remove the accordion but now the "slides" are only very narrow - where the size of each is 400px x 400px.  It also  shows none of the content that is there when expanded.  I'm happy to post the additional HTML & CSS but I cant see an option to do this in the comments?

Comment: Below is an example of the first block in the CSS file.  There are a number of others after that start with ul.accordion li{...  I'm guessing the reference to "accordion" needs to be changed to something else?  Thanks for your patience

`ul.accordion{
    list-style:none;   
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    font-family: Cambria, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }`

Comment: You can try posting it in the original question, or you can post it into JSFiddle and link that.  Without the html and css, no one can see how your page was made.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer - I worked out how to put the CSS & HTML into the original question.

Comment: You have 'display:none' twice in your css.  Remove those.  

Then you will probably want to also remove the html that is div class='heading', and then adjust the font size in css that is 45. 

PS - Adding a link to Fiddle so you can play with it:
https://jsfiddle.net/gjs6La6d/

Comment: Thanks so much Jennifer.  The Fiddle tool was great and I go the result I was after.